# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, antd

```
<div v-if="text" class="click-event" @click="select(record)">
  {{
     ((groupData.filter(group => (group.id === parseInt(text, 0))))[0].categoryName)||'No Group'
  }}
</div>
```

i have this line of code that display categoryName in ant design vue table.

but it's return this error in the console:

```
Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined"
```

but it's still display the right data that i want in the table.
yes i know that i can make a loop in javascript function once catch the api to alter the data. but the Get API containing to many variables in it already. if i want to make a loop, it will cost many line of code.

how can i overcome this error? but still display the categoryName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((groupData.filter(group => (group.id === parseInt(text, 0))))[0].categoryName)||'No Group'
```

Based on your expression I can highlight few problems:

1. Second argument in parseInt is radix and it has to be between 2 and 36, in your code it's 0 which is incorrect. I assume it has to be 10 because I think id stored in decimal numeral system.
2. If any item in your groupData does not match you will get empty array in such case first item in array is `undefined`, and that's why you get such issue.
3. Instead of filter I would recommend you to use find, it has same syntax but it returns first matched result or undefined if there is no match.

Something like this:

```
groupData.find(group => group.id === parseInt(text, 10))
```

4. Don't write such logic inside template part, it's not always obvious and hard to debug.

I hope it helps to you.